# Unlink image while deleting row - pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, unlink

I am trying to `unlink()` an image from a folder while it's corresponding deleting row from database. Deleting the row from the db works great but I can't get the `unlink` to work.

I googled for 2 hours and tried a lot of thing but it's still not working, I think I have some small glitch but I can't figure it out.

Can you suggest what to try.

```
<?php
$pdo = connect();
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $delete_id =   $_GET['delete']; 

    $img = "SELECT slika FROM filmovi WHERE id = $delete_id";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($img);
    $q->execute();
    $row = $q->fetchAll();

    $sql = "DELETE FROM filmovi WHERE id = :filmID";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':filmID', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
    $query->execute();

    $image = $row['slika'];

    unlink("assets/img/movies/.'$image");

    header("Location: index.php?movies");
    die();

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your files aren't actually named with a `.'` at the beginning of the file name.

Comment: no, $image is just one var in code...what to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
unlink("assets/img/movies/.'$image");
```

So say `$image` contains "image.jpg". The path you've constructed is

```
assets/img/movies/.'image.jpg
```

What you most likely want is

```
unlink("assets/img/movies/". $image);
```

Answer (score 0):

One comment helped me but he deleted it. I removed FetchAll and left only Fetch. 
It works now without any errors.
This is the code:

```
<?php
$pdo = connect();
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $delete_id =   $_GET['delete']; 

    $img = "SELECT * FROM filmovi WHERE id = $delete_id";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($img);
    $q->execute();
    $row = $q->fetch();

    $sql = "DELETE FROM filmovi WHERE id = :filmID";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':filmID', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
    $query->execute();

    $image = $row['slika'];

    unlink("assets/img/movies/$image");

    header("Location: index.php?movies");
    die();

}
```

Comment: is this valid way? ... it works. unlink("assets/img/movies/$image");

Comment: yeah, that was me that left that comment. Didn't figure it was to help so I deleted it.

Comment: *"is this valid way?"* - Yes, since the variable is inside a double-quoted statement. *"it works"* - If it works, it's valid then ;-) This however, `unlink('assets/img/movies/$image');` would fail, since the statement is inside single quotes. Variables do not get parsed inside single-quoted statements.